# How do i post text from textarea to mysql database

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, textarea

I have tried the code below but it just wrote '1' in the database instead of the text i wrote. i tried the same with input type="text" and it worked. Why does it not work with textarea?
Ofc i have the if(isset) function too..
PHP:

```
$connectionText = mysql_connect("localhost", "root");
if(!$connectionText){
die("Noget gik galt?". mysql_connect_error());
}
mysql_select_db("textbox", $connectionText);

$t = isset($_POST['tekst']);

$sqlScript = "INSERT INTO forms (tekst) VALUES ('$t')";

mysql_query($sqlScript, $connectionText);
mysql_close($connectionText);

?>
```

HTML:

```
<form action="post.php" method="POST">
<textarea name="tekst" autocapitalize="on" autocomplete="off" 
autocorrect="off" 
class="textBox" maxlength="140"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Offentligør" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: `$t= isset($_POST['tekst']);` thats the problem

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php, `Returns TRUE if var exists and has value other than NULL. FALSE otherwise.`. You also are open to SQL injections and using an out of date driver. Upgrade your driver (mysqli or pdo) and parameterize.

Comment: The code you are writing is open to the most prevalent attack on the web, SQL Injection. Read here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fucntion `isset` only check if given input is defined or not. So it returns true or false as output and when you save it in database you will see only 1 (if $t is true) or 0 (if $t is false).

You should edit this line `$t = isset($_POST['tekst']);` as one of following codes if you want save value of `$_POST['tekst']` in the database:

- if-else version:

```
if(isset($_POST['tekst']))
    $t = $_POST['tekst'];
else
    $t = '';
```

- short if version:

```
$t = isset($_POST['tekst']) ? $_POST['tekst'] : '';
```

Comment: Thanks. The code without the isset() is working like a charm. Marked it as right!

Answer (score 4):

```
$t = isset($_POST['tekst']) ? $_POST['tekst'] : '';
```

Otherwise, `$t` is a boolean

Comment: `isset` returns a boolean, not sanitizes the input.

Comment: ? and : are short if

Comment: @R. A: the code up there works as isset($var) ? if returns true do this : if returns false do this

Answer (score 2):

Function `isset($your_variable)` return `true` if `$your_variable` is defined, otherwise return `false`. So `$t` is TRUE, and it is translated into `1`.

TIP: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection (you should escape `$t` when you build your SQL statement)
TIP 2: Validate the user input first, if all OK then connect to DB (save resources)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know! I appreciate it ;)

Answer (score -2):

You only need to add an `id` value to the `<form>` and then add the form 
attribute to the textarea with the form id value

```
<form id="sample".....>
  <textarea name="aba" form="sample".....></textarea>
</form>
```